# Compare elements of same string array quickly

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, comparison

**EDIT** : I think the C# compiler or something was wrong on the website, I don't know how I could make it any faster than I finally got the project. I switched to Java and it worked fine, exact same logic as the C# project.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int testCases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (testCases > 0)
        {
            int nNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Needed num version for validation
            string[] numbers = new string[nNum];
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)               
                numbers[j] = Console.ReadLine(); //This fills array with numbers                
            Array.Sort(numbers); //Sorts string array
            bool consistent = true; //Checking whether we detect any 'inconsistencies'
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j+1].StartsWith(numbers[j]))
                {
                    consistent = false;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(consistent ? "YES" : "NO");
            testCases--;
        }

    }
}
}
```

This is my final code for C#. It just kept going above 3 seconds no matter what I did.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** I'm gonna make it quick -- I've got this task where I get between 1-10000 unique phone numbers. I have to check whether a number within the array is a prefix of another number i.e. '911', is one phone number, and '911859285' is another number, although, I must print that it "isn't a consistent list" due to the prefix of the second number being the first number.

My original idea was a nested for loop... you can see how this is an absolutely terrible idea considering I'd then have to test 100 million comparisons. I tried a bool to break out of this nested loop, but then realised that if indeed all numbers are valid then we've still got the problem.

**tl;dr** - I need a fast way to compare elements in a string array of 1-10000 elements. If one string is the start of another then it's an invalid list of numbers.

I've seen a bunch of different things like SequenceEquals and LINQ expressions around but I decided to come here for specialised help.

**Updated Code**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool validTestNum = false;
        int testCases = 0;
        try
        {
            testCases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            validTestNum = true;
            if (testCases < 1 || testCases > 40)
            {
                validTestNum = false;
            }
        }
        catch { }

        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
        {
            bool validN = false;
            string nString = ""; //Needed string 
            int nNum = 0; //Needed num version for validation
            while (!validN)
            {
                nNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                validN = true;
                if (nNum < 1 || nNum > 10000)
                    validN = false; //This is validating the amount of phone numbers received
            }

            nString = nNum.ToString();
            string[] numbers = new string[int.Parse(nString)];
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                numbers[j] = Console.ReadLine(); //This fills array with numbers
            }

            bool consistent = true; //Checking whether we detect any 'inconsistencies'
            Array.Sort(numbers); //Sorts string array

            for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                string possiblePrefix = numbers[j - 1];
                if (j < numbers.Length && numbers[j].StartsWith(possiblePrefix))
                {
                    consistent = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (consistent)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES"); //Means the list is consistent
            }
            else if (!consistent)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO"); //Means it isn't
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should show your work and ask for help.

Comment: Is the prefix always 3 digits or can its length vary?

Comment: Also, specify conditions clearly. What constitutes a 'prefix' here? Say you have 3 numbers, `911`, `9115`, and `911534567`. So.. is `911` considered prefixes for both others? And is `9115` a prefix of `911534567`? What's the size of a prefix? All these matter when you're trying to code this.

Comment: @Sach I'll attach my work so far but it's not pretty and kind of doesn't work.

Comment: The prefix is the whole number, so if '9115' is the whole number, and another number is '911585823758' then because the whole number '9115' is the start of the '911585823758' then it's invalid.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The length will vary depending on what the number is, so if '123456' is one number, and '1234565868' is another, then the second number has the start which is identical to the WHOLE first number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the array. A shorter number like '911' will always precede any longer number it is part of. Example of sorted list:

```
910123407
911
911859285
911859286
912348745
```

So, all you have to do is to check whether a given number is the start of the next ones. You can stop as soon as it is not.

```
Array.Sort(a);
for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++) { // Note: we start at index 1, not 0
    string possiblePrefix = a[i - 1];
    for (int k = i; k < a.Length && a[k].StartsWith(possiblePrefix); k++) {
        // a[k] is inconsistent with possiblePrefix , add it to a list or whatever.
        Console.WriteLine($"{possiblePrefix} - {a[k]}");
    }
}
```

Note that the inner loop will not even start looping for most numbers. Only in the rare cases where inconsistencies are found it will loop. So, this is a near `O(n)` algorithm. Sorting is a `O(n log(n))` operation.

You can also replace the inner loop by a simple `if`, if you need to know only the first inconsistency of a series.

Comment: I thank you for your detailed explanation, I've spent quite a bit of time trying to implement it - which I think I've done, I'll update the post with my newer code, I'm going to try Sach's LINQ now. 

The code is definitely faster, and the time-complexity is lower, but on test 3 it's still running over 3 seconds and I cannot figure out why, maybe I've implemented it wrong. https://open.kattis.com/problems/phonelist That's the task I'm trying to complete right now :)

Comment: Theoretically, my algorithm should have a lower time complexity. Note that sorting is probably the slow part. You don't need `j < numbers.Length` in the `if` because this condition was already tested by the `for`. That's only required when using an inner loop.

Comment: I understand the theory of why your's has a lower time complexity. I tried his, and regretfully, it didn't even pass Test 2. Like I said, I've been able to get to Test 3 with your algorithm. Problem is, it's not fast enough - haha! What a conundrum. I've been doing this for like 3-4 hours now, and I did actually try without `j < numbers.Length` first but I put it in after re-reading your answer, just in case.

Comment: Since I don't know what your different tests consist of, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the tests are either, it gave me two test samples and then the website hides the rest of them. It's rather infuriating.

Comment: Use the [Stopwatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) and measure sorting and the inconsistency search algorithm separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `LINQ` solution, if you would like to go that path:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "1",
        "23",
        "456",
        "7890",
        "23457"
    };

    var prefixFound = false;
    foreach (var num in list)
    {
        if (list.Any(x => x.StartsWith(num) && x != num))
        {
            prefixFound = true;
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!prefixFound)
        Console.WriteLine("Consistent list.");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `&& x != num` condition is to exclude the case where a number technically starts with itself.

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`. Not good for an array length of 100 million.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think the array length is 10,000. I believe he mentioned 100 million in case he needed a loop within a loop, so that maximum iterations of that would be 100mil?

Comment: 10,000 sounds more reasonable. But still, he wants to avoid 100,000,000 comparisons.

Comment: Agree. But doesn't C# `Array.Sort()` also have an `O(n log n)` complexity, and worst-case of `O(n ^ 2)`? So by not having to sort, wouldn't this essentially perform equally well? I'm not trying to undermine your answer, just a discussion for me to learn as well.

Comment: See [Array.Sort Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8). In the **Remarks** section it says: *in the worst case, this method is an O(n log n) operation*. At the end of the article it is mentioned that they use a mix of 3 algorithms.

Comment: I appreciate your input, I still have a lot to learn with using LINQ. I think I've implemented it correctly, but it's getting stuck on Test 2 still for 'Time-out', I left the challenge I'm doing in the comments to Olivier's solution. 

I'll add your code that's been implemented to my original post so you can see if I've implemented it correctly :) I tried with/without the `numbersList.Sort();` line